# Create T-SQL Function with table parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I needed to write function with table parameter.

an example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getParentByBrandList
( @_BrandList TABLE(
                        BR_ID INT, BR_Name NVARCHAR(150), BR_ParentBrandID INT, BR_MasterBrandID INT, BR_Role INT,
                        BR_State INT, BR_OwnerID INT, BR_OwnerIP NVARCHAR(50), BR_CreateDate DATETIME, BR_UpdaterID INT,
                        BR_UpdaterIP NVARCHAR(50), BR_UpdateDate DATETIME
                       ) 
)
```

How can I do?

Thanx

Comment: Which are you actually using? 2005 or 2008?

Comment: You can do this using user-defined table types, but only if you are using 2008.

Comment: I use sql server 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beginning from `SQL Server 2008` you can use table valued parameters:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TableType] AS TABLE(
[ID] [INT] NULL
)
GO

CREATE FUNCTION fnTest
    (
      @t [dbo].[TABLETYPE] READONLY
    )
RETURNS INT
AS
    BEGIN

        RETURN (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @t ORDER BY id DESC)

    END
GO

DECLARE @t [dbo].[TABLETYPE]
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1 ),
        ( 2 )

SELECT  dbo.fnTest(@t) AS ID
```

Output:

```
ID
2
```

Answer (score 4):

Check this [tutorial](http://www.sailajareddy-technical.blogspot.in/2012/09/passing-table-valued-parameter-to.html)

Example : **Passing Table Valued Parameter to a function**

```
/* CREATE USER DEFINED TABLE TYPE */
CREATE TYPE StateMaster AS TABLE
(
 StateCode VARCHAR(2),
 StateDescp VARCHAR(250)
)
GO  
/*CREATE  FUNCTION WHICH TAKES TABLE AS A PARAMETER  */
CREATE FUNCTION TableValuedParameterExample(@TmpTable StateMaster READONLY)
RETURNS  VARCHAR(250)
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @StateDescp VARCHAR(250)
 SELECT @StateDescp = StateDescp FROM @TmpTable
 RETURN @StateDescp
END
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
CREATE FUNCTION getParentByBrandList ( )
RETURNS @_BrandList TABLE
    (
     BR_ID INT
    ,BR_Name NVARCHAR(150)
    ,BR_ParentBrandID INT
    ,BR_MasterBrandID INT
    ,BR_Role INT
    ,BR_State INT
    ,BR_OwnerID INT
    ,BR_OwnerIP NVARCHAR(50)
    ,BR_CreateDate DATETIME
    ,BR_UpdaterID INT
    ,BR_UpdaterIP NVARCHAR(50)
    ,BR_UpdateDate DATETIME
    )
AS 
    BEGIN
    --code to create/populate table
    END;
```

You seem to be missing the `returns`, I have added the place-holder for the code. Also, since the name suggests **Get By**, you might be intensing to supply a parameter? if so, you just add to the parenthesis...

```
getParentByBrandList ( param)
```

Answer (score 0):

**This function is from AdevnrtureWorks2012 db from Microsoft which they provide for study purpose.**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetContactInformation](@PersonID int)
RETURNS @retContactInformation TABLE 
(
    -- Columns returned by the function
    [PersonID] int NOT NULL, 
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
    [JobTitle] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [BusinessEntityType] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
AS 
-- Returns the first name, last name, job title and business entity type for the specified contact.
-- Since a contact can serve multiple roles, more than one row may be returned.
BEGIN
    IF @PersonID IS NOT NULL 
        BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [HumanResources].[Employee] e 
                    WHERE e.[BusinessEntityID] = @PersonID) 
            INSERT INTO @retContactInformation
                SELECT @PersonID, p.FirstName, p.LastName, e.[JobTitle], 'Employee'
                FROM [HumanResources].[Employee] AS e
                    INNER JOIN [Person].[Person] p
                    ON p.[BusinessEntityID] = e.[BusinessEntityID]
                WHERE e.[BusinessEntityID] = @PersonID;

        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [Purchasing].[Vendor] AS v
                    INNER JOIN [Person].[BusinessEntityContact] bec 
                    ON bec.[BusinessEntityID] = v.[BusinessEntityID]
                    WHERE bec.[PersonID] = @PersonID)
            INSERT INTO @retContactInformation
                SELECT @PersonID, p.FirstName, p.LastName, ct.[Name], 'Vendor Contact' 
                FROM [Purchasing].[Vendor] AS v
                    INNER JOIN [Person].[BusinessEntityContact] bec 
                    ON bec.[BusinessEntityID] = v.[BusinessEntityID]
                    INNER JOIN [Person].ContactType ct
                    ON ct.[ContactTypeID] = bec.[ContactTypeID]
                    INNER JOIN [Person].[Person] p
                    ON p.[BusinessEntityID] = bec.[PersonID]
                WHERE bec.[PersonID] = @PersonID;

        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [Sales].[Store] AS s
                    INNER JOIN [Person].[BusinessEntityContact] bec 
                    ON bec.[BusinessEntityID] = s.[BusinessEntityID]
                    WHERE bec.[PersonID] = @PersonID)
            INSERT INTO @retContactInformation
                SELECT @PersonID, p.FirstName, p.LastName, ct.[Name], 'Store Contact' 
                FROM [Sales].[Store] AS s
                    INNER JOIN [Person].[BusinessEntityContact] bec 
                    ON bec.[BusinessEntityID] = s.[BusinessEntityID]
                    INNER JOIN [Person].ContactType ct
                    ON ct.[ContactTypeID] = bec.[ContactTypeID]
                    INNER JOIN [Person].[Person] p
                    ON p.[BusinessEntityID] = bec.[PersonID]
                WHERE bec.[PersonID] = @PersonID;

        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [Person].[Person] AS p
                    INNER JOIN [Sales].[Customer] AS c
                    ON c.[PersonID] = p.[BusinessEntityID]
                    WHERE p.[BusinessEntityID] = @PersonID AND c.[StoreID] IS NULL) 
            INSERT INTO @retContactInformation
                SELECT @PersonID, p.FirstName, p.LastName, NULL, 'Consumer' 
                FROM [Person].[Person] AS p
                    INNER JOIN [Sales].[Customer] AS c
                    ON c.[PersonID] = p.[BusinessEntityID]
                    WHERE p.[BusinessEntityID] = @PersonID AND c.[StoreID] IS NULL; 
        END

    RETURN;
END;
```