# SQL Parameter Issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have following SQL query.

```
DECLARE @OID NVARCHAR(MAX) = '(98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105)'

SELECT 
    Name = (SELECT [Name] 
            FROM Point 
            WHERE CAST(OID AS NVARCHAR(10)) = Point),
    Timestamp, 
    ValueNumeric
FROM 
    [IngeniousRPM_Bridge].[dbo].[Value] 
WHERE 
    CAST(Point AS NVARCHAR(10)) IN (98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105) 
    AND [Timestamp] BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-30'  
    AND ValueNumeric IS NOT NULL
```

The above query works fine when `@OID` is hard coded but when I try to pass a `@OID` value as shown below it doesn't return any value in the table. Eventually, I need to create the stored procedure and pass `@OID` value.

```
DECLARE @OID NVARCHAR(MAX) = '(98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105)'

SELECT 
    Name = (SELECT [Name] 
            FROM Point 
            WHERE CAST(OID AS NVARCHAR(10)) = Point),
    Timestamp, 
    ValueNumeric
FROM 
    [IngeniousRPM_Bridge].[dbo].[Value] 
WHERE 
    CAST(Point AS NVARCHAR(10)) IN (@OID) 
    AND [Timestamp] BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-30'  
    AND ValueNumeric IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: The variable @OID you are passing is a varchar and is being treated as such in the IN clause. Depending on what version of SQL you are using, this stack overflow answer might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538697/create-t-sql-function-with-table-parameter, if not, please let us know which SQL and version you are using.

Comment: I am using MS SQL server 2012

Comment: Consider using table valued parameters if possible, this is going to be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this

```
SELECT 98 OID, 'Test' OidTest, GETDATE() [TimeStamp]
INTO #MyTable

DECLARE @OID nvarchar(MAX)='98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105'
DECLARE @dyn nvarchar(MAX)

SELECT @dyn = 'SELECT * FROM #MyTable WHERE OID IN (' + @OID +') and [Timestamp] between  ''2017-11-01'' and  ''2017-12-30'''

exec (@dyn)
```

Answer (score -2):

I can't add comments at the moment...

If you remove the parenthesis from the varchar string does your parameterised version work? essentially you are saying " IN ((98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105))", where I guess what you want is "IN (98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105)"?

Also, I would not use concatenated strings as suggested, especially if you plan to use a stored procedure that accepts an @OID value... you leave yourself open to SQL Injection vulnerabilities. Instead use sp_executesql within your stored procedure and pass in your parameter(s). Copying your code it would look something like this:

UPDATE: have updated the query to include date parameters.

```
declare @OID nvarchar(MAX)='98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105';
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
declare @startDate datetime;
declare @endDate datetime;
SET @sql = N'
            SELECT Name= (select [Name] from Point where CAST(OID AS 
            NVARCHAR(10)) 
            =Point),
            Timestamp, 
            ValueNumeric
            FROM [IngeniousRPM_Bridge].[dbo].[Value] where CAST(Point AS 
            NVARCHAR(10)) 
            In (' + @OID + ') and [Timestamp] between @startDateIN and 
            @endDateIN and 
            ValueNumeric is not null';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
                   ,N'@startDateIN datetime, @endDateIN Datetime'
                   ,@startDateIN = @startDate
                   ,@endDateIN = @endDate;
```

Comment: This won't work at all. You can't use parameters that way.

Comment: very good point... it will not work because it is a comma separated list... I have edited the query, but my comment still stands about using sp_executesql, especially if you are parsing user entry.